# How to count same numbers and return muximum counted numbers value from each column

Tags: sql-server

I have table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID  | C1  |  C2 | C3  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  5  |  8  |  3  |
|  2  |  7  |  4  |  7  |
|  3  |  5  |  8  |  7  |
|  4  |  8  |  2  |  7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to return one number from each column which is counted more. for example in this scenario:

```
+----+----+----+
| C1 | C2 | C3 |
+----+----+----+
| 5  | 8  | 7  |
+----+----+----+
```

What is the best way to do it?

I have written this query but it's for one column only

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    C1, 
    count(*) as Col1
FROM [TableName] 
GROUP BY C1
ORDER BY Col1 DESC
```

Comment: What if i had another row: `5 | 5 | 2 | 1 |`? How will this be displayed? A comma-delimited value for each column?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

**CREATE SAMPLE DATA**

```
use tempdb
create table temp(
    id int,
    c1 int,
    c2 int,
    c3 int
)
insert into temp
select 1, 5, 8, 3 union all
select 2, 7, 4, 7 union all
select 3, 5, 8, 7 union all
select 4, 8, 2, 7
```

**SOLUTION**

```
;with cte as(
    select c1 as val, 'c1' as col from temp union all
    select c2 as val, 'c2' as col from temp union all
    select c3 as val, 'c3' as col from temp
)
select
    max(case when col = 'c1' then val end) as c1,
    max(case when col = 'c2' then val end) as c2,
    max(case when col = 'c3' then val end) as c3
from (
    select
        col,
        val
    from cte
    group by col, val
    having count(*) > 1
)t
```

**DROP SAMPLE DATA**

```
drop table temp
```

Comment: Thank you wewesthemenace. I am impressed with your answers guys.

Answer (score 1):

here is one solution using multiple ctes, one for each column.

```
;with cte1
as
(select row_number() over (  order by count(*) desc) as rn,
       c1
from Table1
GROUP BY C1
)
,cte2
as
(select row_number() over (  order by count(*) desc) as rn,
       c2
from Table1
GROUP BY C2
)
,cte3
as
(select row_number() over (  order by count(*) desc) as rn,
       c3
from Table1
GROUP BY C3
)
select cte1.c1 as c1,
       cte2.c2 as c2,
       cte3.c3 as c3
from cte1,cte2, cte3
where cte1.rn = 1
and cte2.rn =1
and cte3.rn =1
```